Saving Random Forest Predictions Back to Data File
I have developed a random forest classification model and have the model accuracy results along with the confusion matrix, feature importance, and classification report.  Great.
I now want to see how the predictive model is applied to my row level/individual cases...so I can show that (for example) case #3 has a .50 probability of being 1 or 0.
How I could write it back to a CSV file? Is it possible?  Below is the code I've run thus far.
dataset = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\RandForestSample.csv')
dataset.head()
dataset.describe().T 

y = dataset['Retire']
x = dataset.drop(['Retire'], axis=1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

SEED = 42
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.20,random_state=SEED) 

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1, max_depth=3, random_state=SEED)

# fit randomforesstclassifier

rfc.fit(x_train, y_train)

# predict the test set lables
y_pred = rfc.predict(x_test)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
    
# Organizing feature names and importances in a DataFrame
features_df = pd.DataFrame({'features': rfc.feature_names_in_,'importances': rfc.feature_importances_ })
# Sorting data from highest to lowest
features_df_sorted = features_df.sort_values(by='importances', ascending=False)
# Barplot of the result without borders and axis lines
g = sns.barplot(data=features_df_sorted, x='importances', y ='features', palette="rocket")
sns.despine(bottom =True, left =True)
g.set_title('Feature importances')
g.set(xlabel=None)
g.set(ylabel=None)
g.set(xticks=[])
for value in g.containers: 
    g.bar_label(value, padding=2)
    plt.show()


rfc.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = rfc.predict(x_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='d').set_title('Retire or not (0 = not, 1 = retire) for 900 trees with 8 levels')

print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))

I tried
pred_prob = rfc.predict(x_test) # calculate prediction probabilities
pred_class  = np.where(pred_prob >0.5, "Yes", "No") #for binary(Yes/No) category
predictions = pd.DataFrame(pred_class, columns=['Prediction'])
my_new_df = pd.concat([rfc, predictions], axis =1)

But getting the following error:
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type 
'<class 'sklearn.ensemble._forest.RandomForestClassifier'>'; 
only Series and DataFrame objs are valid


Maybe you can try something like my_new_df = pd.concat([x_test, predictions], axis =1) instead of my_new_df = pd.concat([rfc, predictions], axis =1). Note: rfc is the classifier, not the data.
